# How can I do image classification training using yolov8?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, yolo, training-data

As per the YOLOV8 documentation of Classify,
this is the code that's using mnist dataset:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

##### Load a model
model = YOLO('yolov8n-cls.yaml')  # build a new model from YAML
model = YOLO('yolov8n-cls.pt')  # load a pretrained model (recommended for training)
model = YOLO('yolov8n-cls.yaml').load('yolov8n-cls.pt')  # build from YAML and transfer weights

##### Train the model
model.train(data='mnist160', epochs=100, imgsz=64)
```

I have invoices and receipts images dataset in separate folders and want to train for classification problem using yolov8. I am facing issues on where and how to provide image path here, also if yaml has to be used how can I do?

It'd be great if you can provide ideas to complete training for the same.

My images are in this path format:

```
prj
  -train
    -invoice
    -receipt
```

This is my code:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('yolov8n-cls.pt')  # load a pretrained model (recommended for training)

# Train the model
model.train(data="train/", epochs=100, imgsz=64)
```

Error:

```
Ultralytics YOLOv8.0.55  Python-3.8.8 torch-2.0.0+cpu CPU
yolo\engine\trainer: task=classify, mode=train, model=yolov8n-cls.pt, data=train/, epochs=100, patience=50, batch=16, imgsz=64, save=True, save_period=-1, cache=False, device=None, workers=8, project=None, name=None, exist_ok=False, pretrained=False, optimizer=SGD, verbose=True, seed=0, deterministic=True, single_cls=False, image_weights=False, rect=False, cos_lr=False, close_mosaic=10, resume=False, overlap_mask=True, mask_ratio=4, dropout=0.0, val=True, split=val, save_json=False, save_hybrid=False, conf=None, iou=0.7, max_det=300, half=False, dnn=False, plots=True, source=None, show=False, save_txt=False, save_conf=False, save_crop=False, hide_labels=False, hide_conf=False, vid_stride=1, line_thickness=3, visualize=False, augment=False, agnostic_nms=False, classes=None, retina_masks=False, boxes=True, format=torchscript, keras=False, optimize=False, int8=False, dynamic=False, simplify=False, opset=None, workspace=4, nms=False, lr0=0.01, lrf=0.01, momentum=0.937, weight_decay=0.0005, warmup_epochs=3.0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=7.5, cls=0.5, dfl=1.5, fl_gamma=0.0, label_smoothing=0.0, nbs=64, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.7, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.1, scale=0.5, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.0, copy_paste=0.0, cfg=None, v5loader=False, tracker=botsort.yaml, save_dir=runs\classify\train10
Overriding model.yaml nc=1000 with nc=2

                   from  n    params  module                                       arguments
  0                  -1  1       464  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [3, 16, 3, 2]
  1                  -1  1      4672  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [16, 32, 3, 2]
  2                  -1  1      7360  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [32, 32, 1, True]
  3                  -1  1     18560  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [32, 64, 3, 2]
  4                  -1  2     49664  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [64, 64, 2, True]
  5                  -1  1     73984  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 128, 3, 2]
  6                  -1  2    197632  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [128, 128, 2, True]
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\v8\classify\train.py", line 72, in get_dataloader
    loader = build_classification_dataloader(path=dataset_path,
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\data\build.py", line 119, in build_classification_dataloader
    dataset = ClassificationDataset(root=path, imgsz=imgsz, augment=augment, cache=cache)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\data\dataset.py", line 229, in __init__
    super().__init__(root=root)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\folder.py", line 309, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\folder.py", line 145, in __init__
    samples = self.make_dataset(self.root, class_to_idx, extensions, is_valid_file)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\folder.py", line 189, in make_dataset
    return make_dataset(directory, class_to_idx, extensions=extensions, is_valid_file=is_valid_file)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\folder.py", line 102, in make_dataset
    raise FileNotFoundError(msg)
FileNotFoundError: Found no valid file for the classes labels. Supported extensions are: .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .ppm, .bmp, .pgm, .tif, .tiff, .webp
```

I want to train the images and classify the input image as invoice or receipt using yolov8.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please try not to post images of code / errors! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

I put all data in `/dataset/datasetname/train` or test, it worked well.